# normalization of the same vector gives different values at two cases?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, norm

```
 r_capr
Out[148]: array([[-0.42300825,  0.90516059,  0.04181294]])

 r_capr
 np.linalg.norm(r_capr.T)
Out[149]: 0.99999999760432712

 a.T
Out[150]: array([[-0.42300825,  0.90516059,  0.04181294]])

 a.T
 np.linalg.norm(a.T)
Out[151]: 1.0
```

In the above we can see for the same vector we have different norm? Why is it happening?

Comment: What are the `dtype`s of the vectors?

Comment: Is `(r_capr.T == a.T).all()` true? The vectors might be slightly different, but printed with rounding.

Comment: You can check if your two vectors are exactly the same, not just very close, by comparing `r_capr.view(np.uint8)` and `a.view(np.uint8)`. Similarly with the return, try looking at `np.linalg.norm(a.T).reshape(1).view(np.uint8)` and `np.linalg.norm(r_capr.T).reshape(1).view(np.uint8)`.

Comment: They are ndarray. I got r_cap by equating with a.

Comment: Check the dtype. That is probably the root cause.

Comment: If the dtypes of one of the arrays was float32, `dtype=float32` would be included in the output.  Unless the output has been edited, it appears that `r_capr` and `a` are both float64.  (The repr of the numpy ndarray doesn't show the `dtype` value when the type is float64.)  On the other hand, it looks like the ipython session has been edited (where are the `In [...]` prompts?), so who knows...

Comment: When I run this locally I get the exact same results as him using different dtypes (float32 and float64) but printing the arrays doesn't print any dtype information for me. I think I have just a standard install of numpy/scipy (on mac).

Answer (score -1):

Machines are not 100% precise with numbers seeing as they are stored with finite precision (depending on architecture it could be 16 to 128 bits float point) so numbers that are very precise such as getting close to the limit of a float point mantissa are more prone to errors. Given the machine precision error, you can safely assume those numbers are actually the same. When computing norms it may make more sense to scale or otherwise modify your numbers to get less error prone results.

Also using dot(x,x) instead of an l2 norm can be much more accurate since it avoids the square root.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon for a better discussion since this is actually a fairly complex topic.

Your exact error is caused by machine errors but since your vectors are not actually equal (you are showing two logically equivalent vectors but their internal representation will be different) the calculation of the norm is probably being processed with different precision numbers.

See this:

```
a = mat('-0.42300825 ; 0.90516059 ; 0.04181294', np.float32)
r = mat('-0.42300825 ; 0.90516059 ; 0.04181294', np.float64)
print linalg.norm(a)
print linalg.norm(r)
```

and compare the results. It will get the exact results you are seeing. You can also verify this by checking the dtype property of your matrix.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Machines are imprecise, but deterministic. There must be a specific difference between the vectors for the results to differ.